# JavaScript: Determining if a variable is an object literal

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to determine if a given variable is an object literal and nothing else. In the below example, I would like only `a` to return true and any other given object.

```js
var a = {};
var b = [];
var c = new Set();

console.log('typeof:');
console.log('  Literal: ', typeof a === 'object' );
console.log('  Array: ', typeof b === 'object' );
console.log('  Array: ', typeof b === 'object' && !b.prototype );
console.log('  Array: ', typeof b === 'object' && b instanceof Object );
console.log('  Array: ', typeof b === 'object' && !b instanceof Array );
console.log('  Set: ', typeof c === 'object' );
console.log('  Set: ', typeof c === 'object' && !c.prototype );
console.log('  Set: ', typeof c === 'object' && c instanceof Object );
console.log('  Set: ', typeof c === 'object' && !c instanceof Set );
```

`instanceof` seems to work if checking with a hardcoded class, but this is not feasible for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to get the `name` of the prototype's constructor:

```js
var a = {};
var b = [];
var c = new Set();

const type = obj => Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.name;
console.log(type(a));
console.log(type(b));
console.log(type(c));

const isPlainObject = obj => Object.getPrototypeOf(obj).constructor.name === 'Object';
console.log(isPlainObject(a));
console.log(isPlainObject(b));
console.log(isPlainObject(c));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the object's `constructor` property with `Object`:

```js
var a = {};
var b = [];
var c = new Set();

console.log('a:', a.constructor === Object);
console.log('b:', b.constructor === Object);
console.log('c:', c.constructor === Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a function like this should be native, just like Object.isLiteral()

```
var a = {};
var b = [];
var c = new Set();

Object.prototype.isLiteral = function() {
  return this.constructor === Object || false;
};

const value = a.isLiteral();
console.log(value);
```